# SSO with Salesforce as an IdP going to ADFS 2.0

Tags: single-sign-on

I was wondering if it possible to use Salesforce as the IdP to login to Sharepoint or other Microsoft Applications using ADFS 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should definitely be possible. Check out [this article](http://blog.rhysgoodwin.com/cloud/salesforce-sso-with-adfs-2-0-everything-you-need-to-know/). Salesforce also has [an article on the DeveloperForce wiki](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com_and_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Federation_Services). Both articles go through the process of Salesforce initiated IdP and non-Salesforce initiated IdP.

Comment: I believe those 2 are the reverse, they are using ADFS as the IdP not Salesforce.

Comment: They cover both aspects. Salesforce as IdP comes second.